# Error: Validation failed: Images imageable must exist , rails-5.0 , paperclip-5

Tags: paperclip, image-uploading, ruby-on-rails-5

While i was trying to submit the form, following error occured: `Validation failed: Images imageable must exist` and render the same `new.html.erb` view.

If i comment the `file field` in `new.html.erb`. Product is being created successfully.

**ProductsController:**

---

```
def new
    @product = Product.new
end

def create
    @product = Product.create!(product_params)

    if @product.save
        redirect_to products_path, notice: "Product Created Successfully"
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:name, :quantity, :price, images_attributes: [:id, :photo, :_destroy])
end
```

**new.html.erb:**

---

```
<%= nested_form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f|%>

    <h2>New</h2>

    <P> <%= f.label :name %> <%= f.text_field :name %> </P>
    <P> <%= f.label :quantity %> <%= f.text_field :quantity %> </P>
    <P> <%= f.label :price %> <%= f.text_field :price %> </P>
  <%= f.fields_for :images do |p| %>
    <p> <%= p.label :photo %> <%= p.file_field :photo %> </p>
    <%= p.link_to_remove "Remove Image" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add Image", :images %>

  <%= f.submit "Add Product" %>
<% end %>
```

**20160725102038_add_image_columns_to_imageable.rb:**

---

```
class AddImageColumnsToImageable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

  def up
    add_attachment :images, :photo
  end

  def down
    remove_attachment :images, :photo
  end

end
```

**Model:product.rb**

---

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :variant
  has_many  :images, as: :imageable,  dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Model:image.rb**

---

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

  has_attached_file :photo, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :photo, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }

end
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In rails 5, `belongs_to` makes sure that the associated model must exist.
E.g In this polymorphic association, Image model has  `belongs_to :imageable` and Product model has `has_many :images`.
So here in `new.html.erb` we are creating an image, but respective product not exist, so that's why error `Image imageable must exist` .

**Solution**

---

Add `optional: true` while making an association of `belong_to` in Image model.

Image Model now looks like:

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

  has_attached_file :photo, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :photo, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }

end
```